# Three.js - using viewports and EffectComposer together

Tags: javascript, three.js

I recently created a Three.js demo that renders a scene, and then sets the viewport to a smaller section of the window and renders the scene from an overhead camera, creating a mini-map style effect; the code is available at:

http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Viewports-Minimap.html

The relevant code snippet is:

```
// w = window width, h = window height, mapWidth = minimap width, mapHeight = minimap height
renderer.setViewport( 0, 0, w, h );
renderer.clear();

// full scene with perspective camera
renderer.render( scene, camera );

// minimap with orthogonal camera
renderer.setViewport( 0, h - mapHeight, mapWidth, mapHeight );
renderer.render( scene, mapCamera );
```

...and it works like a charm.

Now, I want to extend this example by adding some postprocessing to the scene; I've set up a `THREE.EffectComposer` called `composer`, added the appropriate rendering passes, and I switched `renderer.render( scene, camera )` in the code above with `composer.render()`, but now the minimap disappears; see http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Viewports-Minimap-Effects.html for a live example.

How can I fix this example? More specifically, are there settings in `EffectComposer` that need to be set to work in conjunction with a viewport render afterwards? Or even better, is it possible to add a second RenderPass to the composer that allows us to use a viewport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be changing the code since I first looked at it, but based on your original question, you need to clear the depth buffer before you render the mini-map.

```
renderer.clear( false, true, false );
renderer.render( scene, mapCamera );
```

If your code was working without doing that, I think you were just lucky.

Also, `OrthographicCamera.near` should be a positive number, so the near plane is in front of the camera. Move your orthographic camera back a bit, and set the near plane to a reasonable, positive value.

`OrthographicCamera.left` ( `.right/.top/.bottom` ) should be in world coordinates -- not a function of the window size in pixels.

three.js r.62

Comment: I found a work-around using a second composer to generate the minimap; apparently my luck derived from using either no composers or all composers. You're absolutely right about clearing the depth buffer; I also switched to world coordinates for left/right/top/bottom, which is much nicer to read. Having the near plane value be positive makes much more sense and is consistent with perspective camera settings. Thanks again; as usual, you've taught me some new things and I appreciate your time :)