# Three.js - using orthogonal camera with EffectComposer, camera boundaries now incorrect

Tags: javascript, three.js, rendering, viewport

This question builds off of a previous question, [Three.js - using viewports and EffectComposer together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19714343/three-js-using-viewports-and-effectcomposer-together).

I have successfully created a scene with a "minimap" -- a second camera (orthogonal) is positioned above the scene and renders into a viewport. A live working example where the minimap is displayed using the standard renderer is at http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Viewports-Minimap-Effects.html; the screen correctly appears as follows:
[image]

Next, I wanted to add some postprocessing to the minimap, and created a `THREE.EffectComposer` for it as follows:

```
mapComposer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer, new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(512,512) );
mapComposer.setSize( 512, 512 );
var renderModel2 = new THREE.RenderPass( scene, mapCamera );
mapComposer.addPass( renderModel2 );
var effectFXAA2 = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.FXAAShader );
effectFXAA2.uniforms[ 'resolution' ].value.set( 1 / window.innerWidth, 1 / window.innerHeight );
effectFXAA2.renderToScreen = true;  
mapComposer.addPass( effectFXAA2 );
```

(Complete live code is at: http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Viewports-Minimap-Effects-2.html .) However, the settings for the orthogonal camera are no longer working as expected; the screen appears as follows:

[image]

It appears as though the scene is being rendered to the entire screen space, and then the portion of the scene lying within the viewport boundaries is getting clipped and drawn in that region. I suspect this is the case because:

- changing the coordinates of the lower-left (anchor point) of the viewport changes the image that is displayed, rather than just translating the image displayed before the coordinate change
- increasing the width and/or height of the viewport doesn't cause the image displayed within the viewport to stretch as I expected; rather, it just displays more of the image.

My question is: how can I use an EffectComposer within a viewport as in the second example but keeping the same image boundaries for the minimap as in the first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was twofold: the resolution of the FXAA shader should be set according to the dimensions of the region where the image will be displayed, and I also needed to include a THREE.CopyShader for the image to be translated correctly. The working code is as follows:

```
mapComposer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer, new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(512,512) );
mapComposer.setSize( 512,512 );
var renderModel2 = new THREE.RenderPass( scene, mapCamera );
mapComposer.addPass( renderModel2 );
var effectFXAA2 = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.FXAAShader );
effectFXAA2.uniforms[ 'resolution' ].value.set( 1 / 512, 1 / 512 );
mapComposer.addPass( effectFXAA2 );
var effectCopy2 = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.CopyShader );
effectCopy2.renderToScreen = true;
mapComposer.addPass( effectCopy2 );
```

Corrected live code is at: http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Viewports-Minimap-Effects-2.html

Thanks for listening, StackOverflow community, you are a great sounding board :)

Comment: hmm, and it does not work if you just add a renderToScreen = true to the FXAA shader itself? I thought the CopyShader just copies the image^^

Comment: @GuyGood: I thought so too, but apparently not. I had added renderToScreen to the FXAA shader, but it didn't work out.